# Oracle: ORA-00932 when using cast multiset

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, multiset

I have the following queries which work fine alone:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM users u);
SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM servers s);
```

I want to use them in the same query, so I created this:

```
SELECT CAST( MULTISET( SELECT count(u.id) FROM users u)
             AS NUMBER) AS nr_users,
       CAST( MULTISET( SELECT count(s.id) FROM servers s)
             AS NUMBER) AS nr_servers
FROM dual;
```

And its returning the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got -00932.
```

`count()` returns a number, and I specified the `multiset` as number, so why is it giving me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-queries don't return collection types but scalars, just use

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(u.id) FROM users u) AS nr_users,
    (SELECT count(s.id) FROM servers s) AS nr_servers
FROM dual;
```